# Is there any API in GCP to get the resource usage details..?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-api

I am looking for some API's in GCP that can fetch the usage of resource in terms of usage hours, storage usage etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in obtaining the information about the use of Compute Engine resources so that correlate actual consumption with billing, you can use on the resource usage reports.

Once you set it up, usage reports will be delivered into a preconfigured Cloud Storage Bucket. There are two types of reports that are generated on a regular basis:

- Daily usage reports
- Monthly rollup report

The supported metrics cover resources in question:

- Virtual machines
- Persistent disks
- Images
- Snapshots
- Static IP addresses
- Load balancers

The generated reports contain quantity of consumed resources measured in units (count, seconds, hours, etc) specific for a resource type.

You can manage the usage reports feature with Cloud Console, `gcloud` and API.

Please see [Compute Engine > Doc > Viewing usage reports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/usage-export) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Cloud monitoring API to fetch the resource usage data. Take a look into it:  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rpc

You can list all the available resources and their respective metrics and you can make a **ListTimeSeriesRequest** with metric type as a filter to get the usage data. Here is a code sample in Python to fetch *'cpu_utilization'* for VM instances:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = f"projects/{project_id}"

now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1200), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)

results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

The monitoring API is available in other programming languages too, checkout the documentation to learn more.